# node-webkit: how to display ExtJS Window as simple nw window?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, node-webkit

I have web-version of my internet application. It written in exjts. I need convert extjs window to desktop node-webkit window without including html code as an external webpage.

Is it possible? Maybe you can advise me how i can do that or 3-rd party solution specified for extjs and nw?

**Note:** I have carefully studied the documentation, but nothing like there is not described.